# copy value from one column to another if condition is met in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

df =

| col1 | Aciton1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 1 | C |

I want to edit df, such that when the value of col1 is bigger than 1 , take the value from Action1.

So I will get:

| col1 | Aciton1 | Previous_Aciton |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Initial Action |
| 2 | B | A |
| 3 | C | B |
| 1 | C | Initial Action |

Comment: Please format your question better. It is difficult to understand what your df looks like before and after.

Comment: In addition to the comment of @RajdeepBiswas, I would recommend you to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no negative and `0` values and each group starting by `1` is possible use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
df['Previsou_Aciton'] = df.groupby(df['col1'].eq(1).cumsum())['Aciton1'].shift(fill_value='Initail Action')
print (df)
   col1 Aciton1 Previsou_Aciton
0     1       A  Initail Action
1     2       B               A
2     3       C               B
3     1       C  Initail Action
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'act1': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Previsou_Aciton':['G', 'H', 'I']})
temp = df[df['col1']>1].index
df['Previsou_Aciton'].loc[temp]=df.loc[[x-1 for x in temp]]['act1'].values
```

input df:

[image]

the result:

[image]